# Issues when sorting a list of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have the following list of strings:

```
['0\t ***       *', '1\t    *     *', '2\t     *   *', '3\t      ***', 
 '-1\t            *', '-2\t             *', '-3\t              **']
```

So, I am trying to sort the list such that it becomes:

```
['3\t      ***', '2\t     *   *', '1\t    *     *', '0\t ***       *', 
'-1\t            *', '-2\t             *', '-3\t              **']
```

However, when I use:

```
new_list = sorted(new_list, reverse=True)
```

I get the following:

```
['3\t      ***', '2\t     *   *', '1\t    *     *', '0\t ***       *',
'-3\t              **', '-2\t             *', '-1\t            *']
```

How would I fix it so that it takes -3 into account rather than just - when sorting the strings in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of strings gets sorted alphabetically.

You need to supply a key function, in order to split on the `'\t'` char, and parse the first field as integer:

```
>>> l=['0\t ***       *', '1\t    *     *', '2\t     *   *', '3\t      ***', '-1\t            *', '-2\t             *', '-3\t              **']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('\t')[0]), reverse=True)
>>> l
['3\t      ***', '2\t     *   *', '1\t    *     *', '0\t ***       *', '-1\t            *', '-2\t             *', '-3\t              **']
```

Note that instead of doing `new_list = sorted(new_list, reverse=True)` you can do in-place sort with `new_list.sort(reverse=True)`.

Or, if you don't mind using third party packages, you can have a look at the [natsort](https://github.com/SethMMorton/natsort) package, which seems to solve exactly this kind of problems.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't figure out how to account for the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If your first two char will always be either a number (e.g. `-1`) or a number and `\` or `\t` (e.g. `2\`), you can set a custom key and strip:

```
>>> sorted(i, reverse = True, key = lambda k: int(k[0:2].strip()))

['3\t      ***', '2\t     *   *', '1\t    *     *', '0\t ***       *', 
'-1\t            *', '-2\t             *', '-3\t              **']
```